# run pig 0.7.0 error : ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error

Tags: hadoop, compilation, apache-pig

I have to connect pig to a hadoop which changed a little from Hadoop 0.20.0. I choose pig 0.7.0, and setting PIG_CLASSPATH by

```
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/conf
```

when I run pig, an error is reported like this:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Failed to create DataStorage
```

So, I copy hadoop-core.jar in $HADOOP_HOME to overwrite hadoop20.jar in $PIG_HOME/lib, then "ant". Now, I can run pig, but when I use `dump` or `store`, another error:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job;Lorg/apache/    hadoop/fs/Path;)V

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/   Path;)V
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.BinStorage.setStoreLocation(BinStorage.java:369)
    ...
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:357)
================================================================================
```

Does anyone have encountered this error, or is my compile way not right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section about this issue [in the Pig FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/FAQ#FAQ-Q%3aWhatshallIdoifIsaw%22FailedtocreateDataStorage%22?) which should give you a good idea what's wrong. Here is the outline taken from this page:

This usually happens when you are connecting hadoop cluster other than standard Apache hadoop 20.2 release. Pig bundles standard hadoop 20.2 jars in release. If you want to connect to other version of hadoop cluster, you need to replace bundled hadoop 20.2 jars with compatible jars. You can try:

1. do "ant"
2. copy hadoop jars from your hadoop installation to overwrite ivy/lib/Pig/hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar and ivy/lib/Pig/hadoop-test-0.20.2.jar
3. do "ant" again
4. cp pig.jar to overwrite pig-*-core.jar

Some other tricks is also possible. You can use "bin/pig -secretDebugCmd" to inspect the command line of Pig. Make sure you are using the right version of hadoop.

As pointed in this FAQ section, if nothing works I would advise just upgrading to a recent version of Pig after 0.9.1, Pig 0.7 is a bit old.

Comment: ok, I use pig 0.9.2, and have recompiled as your advice, but another error is reported: `ERROR pig.Main: ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.getConfiguration()Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;`

Answer (score 0):

The Pig (core) jar has a *bundled* Hadoop dependency, which may *differ* from the version you want to use. If you have an old Pig version (< 0.9) the you have the option, to build a jar *without* Hadoop:

```
cd $PIG_HOME
ant jar-withouthadoop
cp $PIG_HOME/build/pig-x.x.x-dev-withouthadoop.jar $PIG_HOME

Then start Pig:
cd $PIG_HOME/bin
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core-x.x.x.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/conf:$PIG_HOME/pig-x.x.x-dev-withouthadoop.jar; ./pig
```

Newer Pig versions contain the prebuilt withouthadoop version (see [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2239) ticket) so you can skip the building process. Furthermore when you run pig it will pick up the withouthadoop jar from PIG_HOME rather than the bundled version, so you don't need to add withouthadoop.jar
to the PIG_CLASSPATH either (provided, that you run Pig from `$PIG_HOME/bin`)

..Back to your question:
Hadoop 0.20 and its modified variant (0.20-append?) can work even with the latest Pig distribution (0.11.1) :
You just need to do the followings:

```
unpack Pig 0.11.1
cd $PIG_HOME/bin
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core-x.x.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/conf; ./pig
```

If you still get "`Failed to create DataStorage`" it's worth to start Pig with `-secretDebugCmd` as Charles Menguy suggested, so that you
can see whether Pig gets the right Hadoop version..etc.

Comment: I have to use hadoop which changed a little from Hadoop 0.20.0. So, my problem is which version of pig I should seletctd and how to compile it to connect this hadoop. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @DavidChuBuaa  Please see my rewritten answer

Comment: Thanks. I had tried your method, but it isn't work yet. Maybe the hadoop I used was changed a lot from hadoop standard version, next I'll try to rewrite pig to match the hadoop.

Comment: @DavidChuBuaa Without knowing the exact Hadoop version you use, I can't help you to get further. If you happen to use any "standard" version (> 0.20.0) then the steps I described should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to run `start-all.sh` from `/usr/local/bin`? I ran into the same problem and I basically retraced my steps in configuring Hadoop itself. I am able to use Pig now.